# Arduino is dead? Error avrdude

Tags: arduino, avr, bootloader, firmware, avrdude

I have a problem with my Arduino.
When I try to upload a sketch any, I get the following error:

```
avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Apr 14 2015 at 16:30:25
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
     User configuration file is "/Users/Antonio/.avrduderc"
     User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

     Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem1411
     Using Programmer              : arduino
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200

    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

Board: Arduino Uno R3
OS : OSx "El Capitan" and "Windows 10"

Now I tried a erase,upload new firmware using dfu-programmer but without success.

I always get the same error.

my arduino is dead?

It seems that the LEDs "The light has a weaker than usual. I do not know if it's just me, is definitely weaker than the" power / ON "

It could be a problem of the bootloader?

Comment: Maybe it is power problem, check adaptor voltage, and check the voltage across VCC and GND in arduino .

Comment: The Voltage across VCC and FND is correct for 5V and 3,3V .

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is try programming it with the Arduino IDE and the "Blink" program to determine if is a hardware issue or code issue.

Comment: I guess you need replacement hardware.